# Jupyterlab: Directory keeps redirecting to where jupyter_notebook_config.py is

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jupyter-lab

I am using Windows Subsystem-Linux (WSL-Ubuntu) on Windows.
I have installed jupyterlab on WSL using Miniconda under a separate virtual environment for my own development.
I am using VSCode to access WSL through the built-in terminal.

However, it is a known issue that the current redirect URL does not work when being redirected from WSL.
To resolve the issue of the inability to redirect to nbserver html, I changed c.NotebookApp.notebook_dir = False.

However, it caused my jupyter notebook to always start my current directory (despite being in a different directory) to where jupyter_notebook_config.py is, even when I deleted it.
There is no way to somehow change this error until I reinstall it (including jupyter notebook and core) completely.

The second time it happened was also when I generated the config file to change the Browser value on the config to use the Chrome installed on my original system.

Using jupyter notebook or reinstalling in a different virtual environment also does not work..

Please help and Thanks in advance!!

[image: How the directory looks like]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have discovered the underlying problem.. Sometimes when you close your code or terminal on VScode (WSL Extension), your jupyter lab/notebook might not always stop running on the localhost port and thus, is causing you to be redirected to the default location where your config.

This can happen even when you Crtl-C on terminal to stop the server from running...

Thus, just run:

```
jupyter notebook stop 8888
```

to make sure that 8888 port is available from all rogue servers and then rerun

```
jupyter lab / notebook
```

There is no need to reinstall jupyter etc.!